# Get each individual date for the last 7 days from todays current date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to get back each date from today's date. Every question I found so far, only gives me one value and not each specific date like the following output below. What I am currently getting back right now keeps iterating through the subtracted date oppose to todays date.

Desired output:

```
08-17-2020, 08-16-2020, 08-15-2020, 08-14-2020, 08-13-2020, 08-12-2020, 07-11-2020
```

What I am currently getting back:

```
08-17-2020,08-16-2020,08-14-2020,08-11-2020,08-7-2020,08-2-2020,07-27-2020
```

JS:

```
function convertToday(data) {
  let date = new Date(data)
  let year = date.getFullYear()
  let month = date.getMonth() + 1
  let day = date.getDate()
  let formatted = "0" + month + "-" + day + "-" + year
  return formatted
}

let d = new Date();
const newDate = [...Array(7)].map((a, b) => convertToday(d.setDate(d.getDate() - b)))
console.log(newDate)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are constantly mutating the `d` variable that you have.

This works for me in `node 14.0` (I guess everywhere else, too)

```js
let d = new Date();
const newDate = [...Array(7)].map((a, b) => convertToday(new Date().setDate(d.getDate() - b)))
console.log(newDate)
```

Notice the `new Date().setDate(...)` instead of `d.setDate(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Reference @edo.n
In case if you need to return date without timestamp or reconverting the date

```js
let d = new Date();
const newDate = [...Array(7)].map((a, b) => {const date = new Date()
date.setDate(d.getDate() - b)
return date})
console.log(newDate)
```